# Get Cell / Range Reference For Named Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple named ranges Say (Report1.. Report2...); each of them contains multiple rows and columns (for instance AI349:AZ368  ... etc) i would like to figure out the actual cell references for the named ranges.

In theory i will be given a list of named ranges and i have to export the actual cell reference for those named ranges.

any help? all i can seem to do is just figure out the cell reference for the first row/column rather than the whole range.

kind regards

Comment: You can also press F3 and click `Paste List`

Answer (score 1):

```
Range("Report1").Address
```

should do the trick.

There are also options:

- `RowAbsolute`: absolute reference of row (default `True`)
- `ColumnAbsolute`: absolute reference of column (default `False`)
- `ReferenceStyle`: `xlA1` or `xlR1C1` (default `xlA1`)
- `External`: If true, the workbook and sheet are given (default `False`)
- `RelativeTo`: Starting cell for relative reference in R1C1 reference mode

see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) for more.

---

There is also the `Range.AddressLocal` property that returns the address in the local language (I think this is only relevant for R1C1 formatting). The options are the same.